# virtualenv with all Python libraries

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

I need to get Python code, which relies on Python 2.6, running on a machine with only Python 2.3 (I have no root access).

This is a typical scenario for virtualenv. The only problem is that I cannot convince it to copy all libraries to the new environment as well.

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages my_py26
```

does not do what I need. The library files are still only links to the `/usr/lib/python2.6` directory.

No I'm wondering, whether virtualenv is the right solution for this scenario at all. From what I understand it is only targetted to run on machines with exactly the same Python version.
Tools like cx_Freeze and the like do not work for me, as I start the Python file after some environment variable tweeking.

Is there maybe a hidden virtualenv option that copies all the Python library files into the new environment? Or some other tool that can help here?

Answer (score 4):

No, I think you completely misunderstood what virtualenv does. Virtualenv is to create a new environment *on the same machine* that is isolated from the main environment. In such an environment you can install packages that do not get installed in the main environment, and with --no-site-packages you can also isolate you from the main environments installed modules.

If you need to run a program that requires Python 2.6 on a machine that does not have 2.6, you need to install Python 2.6 on that machine.

Comment: Not quite, Lennart - tools like PyInstaller can install 2.6-dependent Python programs on machines with older Python versions or no Python at all.

Comment: Well... that's because it includes Python. :) But you are right, that is an option here, especially is the target machine doesn't have a compiler, so he can't install Python.

Comment: This is a good answer because as Lennart points out, the user does not understand the purpose of virtualenv.

Answer (score 4):

I can't help you with your virtualenv problem as I have never used it. But I will just point something out for future use.

You can install software from sources into your home folder and run them without root access. for example to install python 2.6:

```
~/src/Python-2.6.2 $ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
~/src/Python-2.6.2 $ make
 ...
~/src/Python-2.6.2 $ make install
 ...
export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

~/src/Python-2.6.2 $ which python
/home/name/local/bin/python
```

This is what I have used at Uni to install software where I don't have root access.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't clearly explained why `cx_Freeze` and the like wouldn't work for you. The normal approach to distributing Python applications to machines which have an older version of Python, or even no Python at all, is a tool like [PyInstaller](http://pyinstaller.org/) (in the same class of tools as `cx_Freeze`). PyInstaller makes copies of all your dependencies and allows you to create a single executable file which contains all your Python dependencies.

You mention tweaking environment variables as a reason why you can't use such tools; if you expand on exactly why this is, you may be able to get a more helpful answer.