# python setup.py install changes script interpreter

Tags: python, path, installation, virtualenv

I have a Python package that includes a few scripts in a `scripts/` folder. My `setup.py` file includes::

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

scripts = ['script1', 'script2', 'script3']

setup(name='Test',
      version='0.1.0',
      packages=['test'],
      scripts=['scripts/' + x for x in scripts]
     )
```

Each script contains the line::

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the top. However, when I run `python setup.py install` this line gets changed to::

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

automatically in the installed scripts. Is there a way to avoid this? The reason that this is a problem for me is because I am using virtualenv, and so the correct path for the Python executable should be::

```
#/Users/user/.virtualenvs/default/bin/python
```

so I'd rather it left the interpreter set to::

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It turned out that if I removed the `build` directory and tried again, it changed the path to the correct one, but I'd still be interested to know whether it's possible to keep the original `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't touch my shebang!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530702/dont-touch-my-shebang)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The install scripts checks, where the python is installed and changes this python to the proper one. It does it on every machine, where your package is installed.

From docs:

> Scripts are files containing Python
>   source code, intended to be started
>   from the command  line. Scripts don’t
>   require Distutils to do anything very
>   complicated. The only clever  feature
>   is that if the first line of the
>   script starts with #! and contains the
>   word  “python”, the Distutils will
>   adjust the first line to refer to the
>   current interpreter  location. By
>   default, it is replaced with the
>   current interpreter location. The
>   --executable  (or -e) option will allow the interpreter path to be
>   explicitly overridden.