# Can I make a script installed with setup.py use my virtualenv python?

Tags: python, setup.py

This may be a bizarre use case/desire. With `setup.py` I can use the [scripts](https://docs.python.org/2.7/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts) parameter in the setup call to have it install some scripts, easy peasy. However, I plan on installing my application within a virtualenv, and I want my scripts to use the virtualenv python - not the default system install.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/q/4517934/344286 answers my question, actually

Comment: It's not a bizarre use case at all. When deploying my flask apps for instance, I'm always using a virtualenv, although the applications are usually started using supervisord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `setup.py` is smarter than I thought - it [automagically converts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4517934/344286) the hash-bang line to point to the python that it was installed with.

All you have to do is:

- put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the beginning of your script
- make your script executable - `$ chmod +x path/to/script`
- put the script in the setup function

`setup( #stuff goes here
       scripts=['path/to/script'],
       )`

- `(myenv) $ python setup.py develop` (or install)

And magic happens!