# Executable script installed from pip uses the wrong Python path

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to package one of my projects with setuptools. This project deploys an executable script configured in the "setup.py":

```
scripts=['bin/check_mailq.py'],
```

The first line of the "check_mailq.py" file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If I execute "setup.py install", the first line is replaced with the python path of the machine/virtualenv. BTW if I package the project for pypi with the command:

```
python setup.py bdist_egg bdist_wheel upload
```

and then install it with pip in my production machine, the python path is wrong.

```
#!/home/kbyte/pynagmailplugins/venv/bin/python
```

instead of (example):

```
#!/opt/production_venv/bin/python
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Distutils modifies the shebang line with the path to the python you use to run distutils with, so this is expected behavior.  I believe it is setup this way to make sure all the library dependencies needed by your script are in the same python version.

If `pip` is causing the problem, it was likely installed when in a different virtualenv/with a different python.

FWIW, you can run:
python setup.py build --executable="/usr/bin/env python" to manually keep the shebang as is.

See also:
[Don't touch my shebang!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530702/dont-touch-my-shebang), https://github.com/hpcugent/vsc-mympirun-scoop/issues/7

Comment: Great, the `--executable` parameter is the answer. BTW I've to put `--executable="python"` because "/usr/bin/env python" is not enough. Thank you!