# Conda setuptools install changes shebangs to default python install

Tags: python, anaconda, setuptools, conda

I'm having an issue where packages installed via setuptools to python anaconda have shebangs rewritten to the wrong location.

I have installed python anaconda and setuptools package. I have verified that python executable points to the anaconda executable

```
grant@DevBox2:/opt/content-analysis$ which python
/opt/anaconda2/bin/python
```

I need to install a custom package to my anaconda python. It is only installable via setuptools. It includes an command-line executable with the following shebang at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

After installing the package with the following command:

```
sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/opt/anaconda2
```

The executable (content_analysis) appears in a path reachable location. But the shebang at the top has been replaced with the hard coded location of the default python install on the machine.

```
grant@DevBox2:/opt/content-analysis$ which content_analysis
/opt/anaconda2/bin/content_analysis
grant@DevBox2:/opt/content-analysis$ sed -n 1,2p /opt/anaconda2/bin/content_analysis 
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

I have read the following post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530702/dont-touch-my-shebang) concerning setuptools' overwrite of shebangs. The post suggests that the python executable that is first in the `$PATH` *should* be the executable that setuptools uses to replace the shebang. This doesn't seem to be the case for me however.

Note: I cannot hardcode a python executable into my `python setup.py build` command. I need a deployment solution that will work in any environment that has conda installed as the first python in the `$PATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what has been causing all my issues getting python and dependencies properly installed:

Whenever `sudo` is invoked before an executable, in Debian the $PATH variable is automatically changed to a secure path lookup. Here is a demonstration:

```
grant@DevBox2:/opt/content-analysis$ sudo sh
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

versus

```
grant@DevBox2:/opt/content-analysis$ sh
$ echo $PATH
/opt/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

So, when sudo is invoked prior to `sudo python setup.py` the install is reverting back to the default python.

See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path) for discussion