# Python Entry point 'console_scripts' not found

Tags: python, debian, anaconda, setuptools, setup.py

I'm unable to import entry point console scripts in my python package. Looking for help debugging my current issue, as I have read every relevant post on the issue.

Here is what my directory structure looks like:

```
├── ContentAnalysis
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── command_line.py
│   ├── document.py
│   ├── entities.py
│   ├── sentiment.py
│   ├── summary.py
│   ├── text_tokenize.py
│   ├── tokens.py
├── local-requirements.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── server-requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── tests.py
    └── tests.pyc
```

Here is what my setup.py looks like

```
from setuptools import setup

config = {
    'description': 'Tools to extract information from web links',
    'author': 'sample',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': ['ContentAnalysis'],
    'entry_points': {
        'console_scripts': ['content_analysis=ContentAnalysis.command_line:main'],
    },
    'name':'ContentAnalysis',
    'include_package_data':True
}

setup(**config)
```

I've installed the package and verified that content_analysis is reachable from the command line. I've also verified that my ContentAnalysis package is importable from the python interpreter from any cd in the computer. Yet I still get an "Entry point not found error on execution"

```
grant@DevBox2:/opt/content-analysis$ content_analysis -l 'http://101beauty.org/how-to-use-baking-soda-to-reduce-dark-circles-and-bags-under-the-eyes/'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda2/bin/content_analysis", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ContentAnalysis==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'content_analysis')()
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-26.1.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-26.1.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2588, in load_entry_point
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'content_analysis') not found
```

Any help or tips towards debugging this is appreciated

**Edit #1:**

Attempting to debug the issue, I noticed the command_line is not reachable as a submodule within ContentAnalysis

```
>>> import ContentAnalysis
>>> ContentAnalysis.tokens
<module 'ContentAnalysis.tokens' from '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ContentAnalysis/tokens.pyc'>
>>> ContentAnalysis.command_line
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'command_line'
>>>
```

It appears that command_line is not being added to the relevant site_packages folder.

```
grant@DevBox2:/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ContentAnalysis$ ls
data          entities.py   __init__.pyc   summary.py        text_tokenize.pyc
document.py   entities.pyc  sentiment.py   summary.pyc       tokens.py
document.pyc  __init__.py   sentiment.pyc  text_tokenize.py  tokens.pyc
```

I wonder why?

Comment: maybe permission denied

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Investigation of the relevant site-packages folder clued me that my `python setup.py install` command was not putting all the relevant files where they needed to be.

I'm still not 100% of the underlying cause of the issue, but I was only able to get my site-packages folder to truly update by passing setup.py the `--force` argument as in

```
python setup.py install --force
```

Now my site-packages folder contains the relevant command_line.py, and the console entry point works as expected.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem (command_line.py is not being copied), but `python setup.py install --force` doesn't fix it.  Have you learned anything more about this issue?

Comment: One additional potential problem is if a user is running `python setup.py install --force` as compared to  `sudo python setup.py install --force`. It's possible that different users will have different path variables, and you might lose the path variable you need to find the script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255544/conda-setuptools-install-changes-shebangs-to-default-python-install

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up getting around this by using wheels: `python setup.py bdist_wheel` followed by `pip install .`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this is all a bit opaque to debug -- I think the implementation of entry points might suffer from too much indirection.
So entry points work as follows:

- When installing a script with an entry point a placeholder script is placed on your path
- This script contains the name of your package, and the name of the entry point
- This is used to look up an entry in a metadata file called `entry_points.txt` which lives in `egg-info` directories or `dist-info` directories

I suspect this level of indirection allows you to change what entry points point at without reinstalling the binary entry points, which may be deemed as advantageous.

This means that if there are stale or shadowing `dist-info` or `egg-info` files can lead to the wrong entry points being loaded.

A quick

```
strace 2> >(grep --line-buffered entry_points.txt) -e open package
```

will tell you which entry point is being used. You can then verify if this is stale / incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Using `--force` did not solve the problem for me. Instead, I [completely uninstalled the package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1550235/2745116) and then installed it again normally.

Answer (score 1):

I did have a similar issue that occurred after renaming my *entry_point*, in your case that would be changing `"content_analysis="` in the list of the *console_scripts* key. With *python3.6*, *pip19.3.1*, the *entry_point* script was correctly installed in the `install_dir/bin/` directory but I was unable to run it, it raised below error.

> ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'dldemos_server') not
> found

I tried to `pip uninstall`, but the problem was still there;

What solved the issue in my case was:

1. Remove manually every file that have been installed. The entry points in `install_dir/bin/..`, and the module and egg files in `install_dir/lib/python3.6/site-packages/...;`
2. Install the module (I did `python3 -m pip install -e . --user` since I wanted a develop install)

Then I was able to run my entry point.

Answer (score 0):

in your config try changing:`'name':'content_analysis'`

`'console_scripts': ['content_analysis=ContentAnalysis.command_line:main']`
and `'name':'content_analysis'` should be same

Comment: You can have multiple entry points, they need not match "name".