# -bash: image-scraper: command not found

Tags: python, pip

I installed image-scraper using `pip install ImageScraper`.
If I do that again then this the output:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: ImageScraper in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: future>=0.14.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ImageScraper) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setproctitle>=1.1.8 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ImageScraper) (1.1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: SimplePool in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ImageScraper) (0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.1.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ImageScraper) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.2.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ImageScraper) (4.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.1.0->ImageScraper) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.1.0->ImageScraper) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.1.0->ImageScraper) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.1.0->ImageScraper) (2017.11.5)
```

But when I do:

`image-scraper -h`

I get:

`-bash: image-scraper: command not found`.

What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Entry point 'console\_scripts' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280326/python-entry-point-console-scripts-not-found)

Comment: `pip show --files ImageScraper`, look where `image-scraper` is installed and if the directory is in `$PATH`

Comment: @phd It tells me it's in `/Users/doekewartena/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages` but If I cd to there and then do `image-scraper -h` then I still have the same error.

Comment: Try `/Users/doekewartena/Library/Python/2.7/bin/`

Comment: @phd There is an executable there but I can only launch it with `./image-scraper`, any way I don't need the './' prefix?

Comment: (I can't remember the last time that something just works with python / pip...)

Comment: Any idea what is `$PATH` environment variable and how to change it permanently? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bosx%5D+change+PATH

Comment: I know what `$PATH` is but adding `/Users/doekewartena/Library/Python/2.7/bin/` to the `$PATH` won't help cause I still need `./` in front.